# How to handle memory error while building a dataset

Tags: python, dataset, transformer-model

I have a text file with a size of more than 7.02 GB. I have already built a tokenizer based on this text file:

```
from tokenizers.implementations import ByteLevelBPETokenizer
tokenizer = ByteLevelBPETokenizer(
    "tokenizer model/vocab.json",
    "tokenizer model/merges.txt",
)
```

I want to build a dataset as the following:

```
from transformers import LineByLineTextDataset

dataset = LineByLineTextDataset(
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    file_path="data.txt", block_size=128,)
```

Since the size of my data is very large, a memory error will appear.
This is the source code:

```
with open(file_path, encoding="utf-8") as f:
        lines = [line for line in f.read().splitlines() if (len(line) > 0 and not line.isspace())]

    batch_encoding = tokenizer(lines, add_special_tokens=True, truncation=True, max_length=block_size)
    self.examples = batch_encoding["input_ids"]
    self.examples = [{"input_ids": torch.tensor(e, dtype=torch.long)} for e in self.examples]
```

For this reason, since the whole data can't be read at the same time and the lines can't be written to a list as the list gets so big that the program can't handle it, I have changed the source code in the following way:

```
for line in open(file_path, encoding="utf-8"):
        if (len(line) > 0 and not line.isspace()):
            new_line = line.split()

            batch_encoding = tokenizer(new_line, add_special_tokens=True, truncation=True, max_length=block_size)
            self.examples = batch_encoding["input_ids"]
            self.examples = [{"input_ids": torch.tensor(e, dtype=torch.long)} for e in self.examples]
```

However, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File dfgd.py", line 21, in <module>
    file_path="data.txt", block_size=128, #max_length = int(1e30)
  File "C:\Users\DSP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\transformers\data\datasets\language_modeling.py", line 140, in __init__
    batch_encoding = tokenizer(new_line, add_special_tokens=True, truncation=True, max_length=block_size)
TypeError: 'ByteLevelBPETokenizer' object is not callable
```

How can I handle this problem?

Comment: Have u checked here : https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/7234

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thank you. But the memory error has not been solved yet.